# How to hide the Power query code of my report

Tags: powerquery

I have to publish a Power BI report in a workspace shared by my team members , so we all have "Administrator" profiles while the end users have "Member" profile. My objective is to share the dashboards and Data tables (DAX part of the report), but I want to make sure that the query part "Power query" is not visible by any of the users whatever the profile,  is this possible?
Many thanks in advanace for your help!

I didn't try yet any solution

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want users to be able to download datasets from a workspace and view their queries, users must have Viewer access only.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-roles-new-workspaces

Alternatively, you can publish to an app. This gives you a lot more control over what people see, and most importantly, they won't be able to access the dataset at all (assuming they don't have build permissions).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-create-distribute-apps